# Subform totals value to textbox in form returns error

Tags: database, ms-access

I Just want to show totals from subform in a textbox on Form, but it returns error, tried multiple solutions but no luck, even a new query.

Tried some `Dsum`, `Dlookup`, `Sum` and other solutions that I google'd but with no luck, like

```
=Sum([Pitanja subform1].[Form]![ID])
=Sum([Pitanja subform1].[Form]![Datum_prijema])
```

> #Error

Just want "Total" value (like in example = 3) to be shown in textbox `Broj upita`

Image:
https://ibb.co/9NBfnsF

Comment: Please insert your image using the image button on the post editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Sum calculation in texbox in subform header or footer section: `=Sum([Datum_prijema])`. The textbox will not show with Datasheet view but is still available for reference.

Then main form textbox references subform's textbox: `=[Pitanja subform1].Form.tbxSum`

Comment: Thank you  June! It works now, I have been doing this solution on wrong subform.
Now when I open this form, the correct number shows in textbox "Broj upita", but in the table - every row has value of 1 - until i click that row, then it updates the value form subform, I would like to be able to sort by number but the filter button doesn't respond, why is this happening?

Comment: If answer has resolved original question, might mark as accepted. No idea what your table is doing (why are you viewing table?). No idea what the sort/filter issue is caused by. Sounds like you need to post new question(s).