# Subform total on main form

Tags: vba, ms-access

My Access is rusty.  I have a subform with a total calculated.  What I want to do is calculate the total on the main form, because that field is stored in the table.

My problem is similar to this:
[Subform totals value to textbox in form returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295485/subform-totals-value-to-textbox-in-form-returns-error)

However, I can't link the field on the main form to the subform, because it needs to be sourced to a field in a table.

I can't seem to figure out which event this is tied to.  No matter what I do, as soon as I change one of the values the subform totals to the correct number but the main form totals to the previous subform total.  Like, I sum 3, 4 and 5, the subform totals to 12.  I change the 5 to a 15, and the subform correctly sums to 22, but the main form sums to 12.

Comment: Should not save this aggregate calc to table. Textbox on mainform referencing textbox on subform should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subform totals value to textbox in form returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295485/subform-totals-value-to-textbox-in-form-returns-error)

Comment: I actually specifically stated that one didn't answer my question.

Comment: The main form needs to be refreshed or recalculated. Try MainForm.Recalc or MainForm.Refresh or MainForm.Requery after updating your number. One of them should work

Comment: Still an appropriate approach. Then if you still want to save the calculated result (which should not) then use form event(s) to set field value to the textbox calc. Problem with form Requery or Refresh is focus will go to first record of form.