# Sum values in Access Subform that have a checked box and show on Main Form

Tags: ms-access, sum, sumifs, subreport

my problem is similar to [Subform totals value to textbox in form returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295485/subform-totals-value-to-textbox-in-form-returns-error) . I have a subform containing quantities, prices, trades dates, etc. for trades that have occurred and that data will change depending on which ticker is chosen from a combo box in the main form.

There is also a check box in each row of the subform. My end goal, is to have a textbox in the mainform that shows the summation of the quantities for the trades where the checkbox is checked.

I have googled and youtubed for days and the most common answer is the following: create a textbox in the footer of the subform that contains =Sum(IIf([Check]=True,[Quantity],0)) . Essentially, if the checkbox is checked then sum the quantities of the rows with a checked box. Then create a textbox in the mainform that references the textbox in the footer of the subform. This should display the desired quantities; however, I am getting #error in the textbox on the main form instead and I'm not sure why.

Please let me know if I need to clarify further. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are these checkboxes bound to field? Is this db split with multiple simultaneous users? Does the subform textbox show calc? What is the expression on main form? Should be like: `=[subform container name].Form.[textbox name]`

Comment: The checkbox's control source is a field within a SQL table. This SQL table is what I used to create the subform. I'm not sure what you mean by does the subform textbox show calc. If you are referring to the textbox in the footer of the subform then I'm not sure because I can't see that textbox once the form is in form view. The expression in the textbox on the main form looks like this: =[subfrmPIPE_CleanUps].[Form]![txtFooterSelectedSum]

Comment: Set the subform for Continuous View so the textbox can be seen. Then can change to Datasheet once confirmed it's working. Is subfrmPIPE_CleanUps also name of subform container control? I always name container different from the object it holds, like `ctrPIPE`. Expression must reference container control, not form name. Try dot instead of ! character. Be aware multiple simultaneous users will conflict when checking records.